# Iterate Over List and Match in Python

Tags: python, match

I have a list with string values in it:

```
iwx = ['Ok', 'Hi', 'Hi', 'Hi', 'Hi', 'He', 'Hy', 'Hy', 'Hy', 'Hl', 'Gb']
```

I'm trying to make it so I iterate over the strings in the list it condenses it. My expected output is:

```
['Ok', 'Hi'*4, 'He', 'Hy'*3, 'Hl', 'Gb']
```

My code is:

```
ix = []

iwx = ['Ok', 'Hi', 'Hi', 'Hi', 'Hi', 'He', 'Hy', 'Hy', 'Hy', 'Hl', 'Gb']

iwy = list(enumerate(iwx))

for i,x in iwy:
    n = 0
    n += 1
    tz = [iwy[x:i+11] for x in range(0, len(x))]
    print(tz)
```

This is where I get lost. Please help.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account. [On topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and ... [the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) apply here.

Comment: There is one distinct problem with your posting: your expected output is not a legal representation for any built-in class.  To get this, you will need to write your own function to transform the given list into the string you wish to see.

Comment: Your expected output does not make really sense in python. What exactly are you trying to achieve, counting the frequency of the values in your list ?

Comment: When you expand that condensed version, you won't get the original list back. (FYI)

Comment: You are initializing `n` inside the loop itself, then incrementing it by one, is that intentional?

Comment: That's what i'm trying to figure out. Whether to use the count feature to give me the Hi*4 which i imagine would look like f'{i]*{n}' or something like that where i = Hi and n = 4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if this is what you want, but if your hope is just counting the number of times each string appears, this may be a solution:

```py
from collections import Counter
[(i,j) for i,j in zip(Counter(iwx).keys(), Counter(iwx).values())]
```

Note, if you want to have a dictionary instead (better for convenience), just use:

```
dic_name = dict([(i,j) for i,j in zip(Counter(iwx).keys(), Counter(iwx).values())])
```

Comment: That was exactly what I was looking for. Thank you.

Comment: No problem, let me know if you have any more questions.

Comment: Edited answer since you wanted a dictionary :)

Answer (score 0):

As the comments imply, I am finding it difficult to understand the intended result and usage of certain lines. Below is the code which could help you achieve your result in a different fashion.

```
iwx = ['Ok', 'Hi', 'Hi', 'Hi', 'Hi', 'He', 'Hy', 'Hy', 'Hy', 'Hl', 'Gb']
d = {}
# Creating a dictionary to maintain uniqueness of the strings as keys
# And maintain the count of occurrence as values
for i in iwx:
    if i in d:
        d[i] += 1
    else:
        d[i] = 1
print(d)
# d = {'Ok': 1, 'Hi': 4, 'He': 1, 'Hy': 3, 'Hl': 1, 'Gb': 1}
```

You can use `OrderedDict` if the order of the string in the list needs to be preserved.

Comment: I was just thinking of using a dictionary. Thank you so much. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your goal is to count how many times each value exist :

this should work:

```py
ix = []

iwx = ['Ok', 'Hi', 'Hi', 'Hi', 'Hi', 'He', 'Hy', 'Hy', 'Hy', 'Hl', 'Gb']

occurences = {}


for i in range(0, len(iwx)):
        if iwx[i] not in occurences:
            occurences[iwx[i]] = 1
        else:
            occurences[iwx[i]] += 1

print(occurences)
```

the result is :

```py
{'Ok': 1, 'Hi': 4, 'He': 1, 'Hy': 3, 'Hl': 1, 'Gb': 1}
```